# PDF file isn't centered in webBrowser control of Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pdf, itext

I'm trying to make a PDF utility app that will allow users to merge and split PDF files. The only problem I have right now is that on load my app shows the pdf file off center. Example
[image: PDF off center iamge]

In order to make the PDF file center I have to manually mouse-click the dark grey area that is shown when the PDF file is off center. After that the pdf file will be center like so [image: PDF Center image]

So is there anyway possible to make the PDF file centered automatically like the 2nd image?

Code below is how I call webBrowser1 that is rendering the pdf file.

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string filename = "pdf_example.pdf";
        string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, filename); // grab pdf file from root program file

        webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(path); // <-- input pdf location, WebBrowser Code section, REDACTED   

        //"button1" == "Load PDF Files", EventHandler
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_click);

        //"button2" == "Save PDF Files", EventHandler
        button2.Click += new EventHandler(button2_click);

        //"button3" == "Merge PDF Files", EventHandler
        button3.Click += new EventHandler(button3_click);

        //"button4" == "Split PDF Files", EventHandler
        button4.Click += new EventHandler(button4_click);

    }
```

I was thinking it had to do with the pdf being loaded before the Form1 window was completely loaded. So I tried making a method and set Form1 Shown properties to this method.

```
void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string filename = "pdf_example.pdf";
        string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, filename); // grab pdf file from root program file

        webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(path); // <-- input pdf location, WebBrowser Code section, REDACTED  

    }
```

It didn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Also I completely redid the app to use axAcroPDF control to render PDF instead of webBrowser control to render PDF and I still got the same problem where the PDF file was off-center.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference. The problem was that my monitor resolution was set to 4k. This caused the pdf file to be open off center in IE every-time for some reason. If the program was open in a 1920x1080 resolution monitor then the pdf file is perfectly centered every-time the program starts.